# how to make resizable use %instead of px in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a textarea where I used jquery  resizable .

```
jQuery("#TxtOrig").resizable({maxWidth: 900 });
```

This query will allow me to resize to 900px. The textarea gets squeezed with resizing of the page, in that case I want to have my textarea to have maxwidth less  if page is resized.

Can I have my maxWidth dynamic like with %? like 100% within the div it is included?

```
 <div id="DivOrig">
  <textarea id="TxtOrig" name="wl_text" wrap="soft" >Type or paste here to translate text...</textarea>
 </div>
```

css

```
#DivOrig {
  justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
   /* min-width: 918px; */
    background-color: #eef6f9;
    border: 1px solid #d5e1e5;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px 1px #d5e1e9;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```

since my DivOrig is 50%, so can I have a jquery resizable that everytime the textarea is resized with page resize, the textarea now can only be minimized to within tha that div? If i use MaxWidth as 900, it is px so I can resize outside of the div as well. But I want not to have that.

Comment: on resize of window set the max width?

Comment: @epascarello yes , is there a way that I can have limit to my resize dynamicaly? that is after resize of the browser, the window will be smaller and now the resize amount should decrease as well

Comment: calculate the current maxwidth based on current window and use `$(window).resize()` to re-calculate it when the window size changes.